# Symfony2, how to do aggregation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I try to select documents by grouping them with a part of a field, so I need to use aggregation as I looked for in the Internet, but I didn't find any documentation about it, I did the grouping with the entire field, and now I need to do it with just a part from this field, the function that do this for me is in my repository and here it is:

```
$result = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('AcmeSiteBundle:Statistique')
    ->group(array('date'=>1), array("count"=>0))
    ->reduce('function (obj, prev) {
            prev.count++;

    }')
    ->field('name')->IN(array($name))
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

I group the document by "date", and just for a $name that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds this answer when doing a Google search and turns up a blank, there are two ways of getting the aggregation builder.

1 - From within a repository

```
createAggregationBuilder()
```

2 - From Document Manager

```
$dm->createAggregationBuilder('DocumentName');
```